Add Identity in Blazor 9 project
I'm creating a new project using .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid and Web App with .NET9. I want to add Identity to the project. To do so, right-click on the web project, select  Add and then New Scaffolded Item and then select Blazor Identity from the window.

Then, I select all the dropdown lists with the default values.

After clicking Add, I get this error

What do I have to do in order to add Identity to my project? Is it better if I copy a n old implementation?
